# Сетка в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте! Попытаюсь объяснить свою проблему. На главной странице сайта размещены сеткой посты(сol-md-3), дело в том, что посты имеют разную высоту, а посты на следующей строке начинаются там, где заканчивается высота самого длинного поста, как сделать так, что бы отступы по высоте между постами были одинаковыми? картинки загружать не могу, что бы точно показать в чём проблема, http://www.cyberforum.ru/web-design/thread1111770.html - здесь я задал этот же вопрос, картинки для наглядности там приложены

Comment: скорее за все что у вас столбики (`col-*`) лежат внутри контейнера `row`

Comment: @jmu даже, если row убрать ничего не изменится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

весь секрет в том чтоб использовать "fluid container":

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row well">
                    Column A. Block 1<br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column A. Block 2<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column A. Block 3<br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row well">
                    Column B. Block 1<br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column B. Block 2<br /> <br /> <br /><br /><br /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column B. Block 3<br /> <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row well">
                    Column C. Block 1<br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column C. Block 2<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column C. Block 3<br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column C. Block 4<br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row well">
                    Column D. Block 1<br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column D. Block 2<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column D. Block 3<br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column D. Block 3<br /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row well">
                    Column D. Block 3<br /> <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @jmu Спасибо!

Comment: В чем смысл использования именно `fluid-container` вместо просто `container`? В контексте данной задачи вопрос решает именно `well` заключенный в ячейку фиксированной ширины `col-md-3`. А какой вокруг них будет `container` особой роли не играет.